# Can't dynamically set component identifier

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, identifier

I have a `p:inputText` field  inside a dataTable and I'm trying to set its identifier dynamically.

However I get the following error:

> component identifier must not be a zero-length String

None of the String used as id are null or of zero-length

```
<h:form id="updateform">
            <p:dataTable id="updatetable" value="#{EditingBean.row}" var="column"
                                 style="width: 983px; overflow-x: auto; white-space: normal;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{EditingBean.currentStatement.statementName}" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:column rendered="#{column.display}" style="white-space: normal;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{column.alias}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column rendered="#{column.display}" style="white-space: normal;">
                    <p:inputText id="#{column.name}" value="#{column.value}" />
                </p:column>
                <f:facet name="footer" style="text-align: right;">
                    <h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{EditingBean.update()}"
                        ajax="false" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Check the value of #{colum.name} for every object in your #{EditingBean.row} object again. If even one name attribute is null or "" (an empty string), you'll get the error.

Comment: I have, absolutely none of them are null or "".

Comment: Here are the values : mep_ident,  mep_ptrpartident,  mep_ptrpasident,  mep_code_doc,  mep_production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` attribute must be set during view build time.

However, as `#{column}` is declared as `<h:dataTable var>`, it's only available during view render time. As it runs after view build time, it's thus `null` during view build time.

I'm not sure about the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that doing this would be the right solution. The code is not self-documenting enough to properly guess it. So it's hard to give a suitable answer. In any case, you've basically 2 options:

1. Use an iterating tag which runs during view build time, such as JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

   ```
   <c:forEach items="#{EditingBean.row}" var="column">
       ...
       <p:inputText id="#{column.name}" ... />
   ```
2. You perhaps actually don't need a dynamic ID at all. Give it a fixed ID.

   ```
   <p:inputText id="name" ... />
   ```

   JSF will already take care of generating unique IDs (prefixed with row index) in HTML output. Rightclick page and do *View Source* to see it yourself.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: I need to use the name for validating the input as I don't know beforehand what type the input is supposed to be.

Comment: Just set a CSS class on `styleClass` like `styleClass="phone"`, `styleClass="url"`, `styleClass="email"`, etc. Those kind of inputs can impossibly be unique anyway, so your `id` approach makes in first place already no utter sense. With jQuery you can easily grab them as in `$(".phone")`, `$(".email")`, etc.

Comment: A column has usually more than one row, right? So you end up with as many inputs in one column as many rows are, right? So with e.g. 10 rows you end up having 10 phone inputs, etc.

Comment: That's fine. This still doesn't mean that those inputs are unique in HTML context. There are still multiple of them, only conditionally shown/hidden. A CSS class is therefore the right and most easy solution.

Comment: My problem though is that I then need to access the field when validating (I'm using `<f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{EditingBean.validate}" />`) Is it possible to access components by StyleClass like it is by id?

Comment: Just set the validator on the input itself? Why do you keep trying to solve things the hard way?